# Seperating .csv file into columns?

Tags: c, csv, struct

I have a project to make a program that reads a .csv file that takes 2 inputs, first input is the column and the second input is a keyphrase. What it needs to do is to find the keyphrase in the chosen column and prints out every line with that keyphrase in that column.
I've been stuck on this for a while and just cannot figure it out at all.

Problem starts from line 75 where I get an error 'request for member 'Location1' in 'aol', which is of non-class type 'data [4000]''

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct data{
    char Location1[100];
    char Location2[100];
    char price[10];
    char rooms[10];
    char bathrooms[10];
    char carparks[10];
    char type[100];
    char furnish[100];
};


struct data aol[4000];
int printedlines;


// Untuk membaca isi file csv
void fileread() {
    FILE *fp = fopen("AOLDATA.csv","r");
    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("Error! File not found.");
        exit(0);
    }
    while(fscanf(fp, "%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^\n]", aol[printedlines].Location1, aol[printedlines].Location2,
    aol[printedlines].price, aol[printedlines].rooms, aol[printedlines].bathrooms, aol[printedlines].carparks,
    aol[printedlines].type, aol[printedlines].furnish) != EOF) {
        printedlines++;
        fgetc(fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

void searchData(char *keyword) {
    int found = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < printedlines; i++) {
        if(strstr(aol[i].Location1, keyword) || strstr(aol[i].Location2, keyword) ||
           strstr(aol[i].price, keyword) || strstr(aol[i].rooms, keyword) ||
           strstr(aol[i].bathrooms, keyword) || strstr(aol[i].carparks, keyword) ||
           strstr(aol[i].type, keyword) || strstr(aol[i].furnish, keyword)) {
            printf("%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s\n", aol[i].Location1, aol[i].Location2, aol[i].price, aol[i].rooms,
            aol[i].bathrooms, aol[i].carparks, aol[i].type, aol[i].furnish);
            found++;
        }
    }
    if(!found) {
        printf("Data not found!");
    }
}

int main(){
    int option;
    char line[100];
    
    fileread();
    
    printf("What do you want to do?\n1.Display data\n2.Search Data\n3.Sort Data\n4.Export Data\n5.Exit\n");
    printf("Your choice: ");
    scanf("%d", &option);
    
    
    if(option == 1){
    int howmanylines;
    int printedlines = 0;
    printf("Number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &howmanylines);
    for(int i = 0; i < howmanylines; i++) {
        printf("%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s\n", aol[i].Location1, aol[i].Location2, aol[i].price, aol[i].rooms,
        aol[i].bathrooms, aol[i].carparks, aol[i].type, aol[i].furnish);
    }

    }else if(option == 2){
            char choice[100];
            char column[100];
            
            printf("Choose column: ");
            scanf("%s", column); getchar();
            printf("What do you want to find? ");
            scanf("%s", choice); getchar();
            
            
            if(choice == aol.Location1){
                for(int i=0; i < 3940-1; i+8)
                printf("%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s\n", aol[i].Location1, aol[i].Location2, aol[i].price, aol[i].rooms
                , aol[i].bathrooms, aol[i].carparks, aol[i].type, aol[i].furnish);
            }
        }
        
    return 0;
}
```

Input file exmple:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F     G      H
NY  US  10  20  30  40   Bad   Expensive
LN  UK  20  30  40  50   Good  Expensive
JK  IN  20  10  50  20   Good  Cheap
```

Comment: Post a least a few lines of the input file... It is hard to imagine that one here will type in a test file for your program...

Comment: I edited it to have an example of the input file at the bottom

Comment: The way you do it, it ends up in a endless loop if one single line does not match the pattern. That's why I would fetch the while line with `fgets` and then parse it with `sscanf`. But to be honest, I would split the line using `strtok` as with it you have way more control over invalid lines.

Comment: The program does not even compile yet.  At the end, this ` if (choice == aol.Location1)` is wrong. `aol` is an array. And `Location1` is `char[100]` so you can not use `==` and the index is missing

Comment: And the last `for` is wrong: `for (int i = 0; i < 3940 - 1; i + 8)` `i+8` is an expression and evaluates to `0` or `1`

Comment: always test the return of `fscanf` against the number of specifiers, `8` in your case.

Comment: Your csv input example contains no commas but your code requires it.  Please edit question to clarify which it is.

Comment: When reading strings with `scanf()` you need to specify the maximum field width to avoid buffer overflows.

Comment: See [How do I properly compare strings in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8004237/15168) for how to compare strings.

Comment: What's the example input for search by column name?  A or Location1?

Answer (score 1):

1. `choice == aol.Location1`: compares two pointers (always false as used here) instead you want to use `strcmp()` to compare strings.
2. For search, it's not clear if you want to search on the struct member name or if the first row is a header and you want to enter a header column name.  I used the former as it's a step less but I will update my answer if you clarify that you want the latter.
3. (Not fixed) If the first line is a header then you want to use a different type for it, say, `char **header` as it's doesn't have the constraint as the data.  If the type of a column was an `int` then the column header would still be `char *`.
4. (Not fixed) Consider using a simpler data model.  For example an array of lines (`char **data`).  Then everything will become much more tractable:

   ```
   header_print(header);
   int column = header_column(header, name)
   for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
      if(!strcmp(column_value(data[i], column), value))
        // ...
   ```
5. Always use a maximum field width when reading strings with `scanf()` to avoid buffer overflows.  I introduced symbolic constants of the string lengths, and used the `str()` macro to generate suitable format strings.
6. Always check the return value of I/O operations like `fprintf()` or `scanf()` otherwise you may be operating on uninitialized variables.
7. Use symbolic constants like the number of fields or name of each of the options instead of hard-coding it.  Especially if you need to use it more than once.
8. Don't use global variables.  It makes your code much harder to test.
9. Reformat menu for readability.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define FIELDS 8
#define LOCATION_LEN 99
#define FURNISH_LEN 99
#define TYPE_LEN 99
#define STR_LEN 9
#define str(s) str2(s)
#define str2(s) #s

struct data {
    char Location1[LOCATION_LEN+1];
    char Location2[LOCATION_LEN+1];
    char price[STR_LEN+1];
    char rooms[STR_LEN+1];
    char bathrooms[STR_LEN+1];
    char carparks[STR_LEN+1];
    char type[TYPE_LEN+1];
    char furnish[FURNISH_LEN+1];
};

void fileread(const char *path, struct data **aol, size_t *n) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(path, "r");
    if(!fp){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error! File not found.");
        exit(1);
    }
    *aol = NULL;
    for(*n = 0;; (*n)++) {
        struct data r;
        int rv = fscanf(fp,
            " %" str(LOCATION_LEN) "[^,],"
            "%" str(LOCATION_LEN) "[^,],"
            "%" str(STR_LEN) "[^,],"
            "%" str(STR_LEN) "[^,],"
            "%" str(STR_LEN) "[^,],"
            "%" str(STR_LEN) "[^,],"
            "%" str(TYPE_LEN) "[^,],"
            "%" str(FURNISH_LEN) "[^\n]",
            r.Location1,
            r.Location2,
            r.price,
            r.rooms,
            r.bathrooms,
            r.carparks,
            r.type,
            r.furnish
        );
        if(rv == EOF)
            break;
        if(rv != FIELDS) {
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid input line %zu\n", *n+1);
            exit(1);
        }
        struct data *tmp = realloc(*aol, sizeof *tmp * (*n + 1));
        if(!tmp) {
            fprintf(stderr, "realloc failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        *aol = tmp;
        (*aol)[*n] = r;
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

int name_offset(const char *name, size_t *offset) {
    if(!name) return -1;
#define MAP(name) {#name, offsetof(struct data, name)}

    struct {
        const char *name;
        size_t offset;
    } map[] = {
        MAP(Location1),
        MAP(Location2),
        MAP(price),
        MAP(rooms),
        MAP(bathrooms),
        MAP(carparks),
        MAP(type),
        MAP(furnish)
    };
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof map / sizeof *map; i++)
        if(!strcmp(name, map[i].name)) {
            *offset = map[i].offset;
            return 0;
        }
    return -1;
}

void search(const struct data *aol, size_t n, const char *name, const char *value) {
    size_t offset;
    if(name && name_offset(name, &offset)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "column name %s was not found\n", name);
        return;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if(!name || !strcmp(((char *) &aol[i])+offset, value))
            printf(
                "%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s\n",
                aol[i].Location1,
                aol[i].Location2,
                aol[i].price,
                aol[i].rooms,
                aol[i].bathrooms,
                aol[i].carparks,
                aol[i].type,
                aol[i].furnish
            );
}

int main(void) {
    struct data *aol;
    size_t n;
    fileread("AOLDATA.csv", &aol, &n);

    enum {DISPLAY = 1, SEARCH, SORT, EXPORT, EXIT};
    printf(
        "What do you want to do?\n"
        "%d.Display data\n"
        "%d.Search Data\n"
        //"%d.Sort Data\n"
        //"%d.Export Data\n"
        "%d.Exit\n"
        "Your choice: ",
        DISPLAY,
        SEARCH,
        // SORT,
        // EXPORT,
        EXIT
    );
    int option;
    if(scanf("%d", &option) != 1 || option < DISPLAY || option > EXIT) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid option\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(option == DISPLAY) {
        search(aol, n, NULL, NULL);
    } else if(option == SEARCH) {
        char name[LOCATION_LEN+1];
        printf("Choose column: ");
        scanf(" %" str(LOCATION_LEN) "s", name);

        printf("What do you want to find? ");
        char value[LOCATION_LEN+1];
        scanf(" %" str(LOCATION_LEN) "s", value);

        search(aol, n, name, value);
    }
    free(aol);
}
```

I modified your input file to match your parser:

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H
NY,US,10,20,30,40,Bad,Expensive
LN,UK,20,30,40,50,Good,Expensive
JK,IN,20,10,50,20,Good,Cheap
```

and example run:

```
$ ./a.out
What do you want to do?
1.Display data
2.Search Data
5.Exit
Your choice: 1
A                   B                   C                   D                   E                   F                   G                   H                   
NY                  US                  10                  20                  30                  40                  Bad                 Expensive           
LN                  UK                  20                  30                  40                  50                  Good                Expensive           
JK                  IN                  20                  10                  50                  20                  Good                Cheap
```

```
$ ./a.out
What do you want to do?
1.Display data
2.Search Data
5.Exit
Your choice: 2
Choose column: furnish
What do you want to find? Expensive
NY                  US                  10                  20                  30                  40                  Bad                 Expensive           
LN                  UK                  20                  30                  40                  50                  Good                Expensive
```